# VueJs binding properties to conditions

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs-datepicker

I am using [vue-datepicker](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker&ved=0ahUKEwjOwrCKtoDYAhUHO48KHctSCacQFggkMAA&usg=AOvVaw32Rit4hzO28DipUfHLV7TX) and it has certain properties like disabled, calendar-button, etc. I want to bind these properties to  conditions or a Boolean in my data object.

I tried `<date-picker disabled-picker=true></date-picker>`

But it throws error: `expected Boolean, string given`

What I am expecting is, if a condition is true then output should be like:

`<date-picker disabled-picker></date-picker>`

If condition is false,

`<date-picker></date-picker>`

I know I can use a v-if wrapper (v-if else) around it but I am looking for a v-bind solution like how we use for html attributes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `:disabled-picker="isDisabled"` parsed like a string.

You should go for `:disabled-picker="isDisabled"` insead.

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
     isDisabled: true
    }
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/w03ork28zw

Comment: Sure. Will try that. Thanks for that. If it works will mark this as answer.

Comment: That didn't work. Actually I wrote the incorrect property name. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Updated with example

Comment: Thanks for the help. It solved the problem. I am still wondering why it didn't work the first time you suggested to put double quotes (:).

Answer (score 2):

You should do:

```
<date-picker :disabled-picker="someVariableWithTrueOrFalse"></date-picker>
```

Be sure to declare `someVariableWithTrueOrFalse: false` in your data section.

You said you just want the attribute to show for true and not show for false but

```
<date-picker disabled-picker></date-picker>
```

basically equates to the example I provided initially. Setting the value to false is the same as the attribute not being there.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Wish there was an option to mark two answers right.